# Parsing and accessing untrusted XML

Tags: xml, erlang, elixir

I have some kind of XML transformation gateway and it accepts XML in one format and produces it to the other from sources which I would rather not trust to. Now, those transformations can be either trivial, as in changing a couple of attrs here and there, or quite complex, where I need to disassemble the entire input and build output from the scratch. So, basically I have two problems:

1. Parsing XML. It needs to be fast ( preferably ) and work without blowing up the atoms table ( I am looking at you, `xmerl` ) since sources are not that reliable.
2. Easily accessing deeply nested elements to retrieve information required for the rebuild.

While there are a few options for parsing XML, like `fast_xml` and `erlsom` libraries, they generate structures that are rather hard to access since they are not comparatible with `xmerl_xpath` and so far that's the only sane way I have found to get deeply nested data.

So the question is whether there is a way to achieve those goals without spending lots of time on creating my own solution?

P.S. Seriously? Trying to close this question? I am not asking what library to use out of 100 available, I am asking how to solve a problem which may occur for most of the people that decide to use Erlang for XML handling.

Comment: what about sweetxml?

Comment: @CallMeNorm A quote -> `SweetXml is a thin wrapper around :xmerl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find any ready solution for this problem so I ended up doing the following:

1) Use `Erlsom` or `Fast XML` Erlang packages for parsing XML string into what's called simple format, like the following: `{"tag", [{"attr", "value"}], ["text node"]}` where children can be a list with one string, as in the example, or a list of nested elements.

2) Implement my own function to get nested elements according to given path, for the most basic usage doesn't take more than 50 LOC

3) Implement my own XML builder since `xmerl` cannot be used again because of the atoms problem. Now, this part is rather controversial because there is a good chance it has some number of bugs and does not support comments, cdata and whatnot but with some testing with proper data, hopefully I will be able to make it stable enough. What choice do I have anyway?!